# keep the leading zeros when echo'ing a string to a variable

Tags: unix

I'm trying to keep the leading zeros on a number when I echo it to a csv file but I cannot find a way w/o echoing it with a single quote. How can I do this using a bash script?

After going through a file and extracting what I want and storing it in a variable, I echo it to a variable that's mapped to a file.

file name:
`` TMP_RESULT_STORE="/tmp/AdvertisedTotals_GLB_`date +%y%m%d`.csv" ``

Lets say:
`SYM=0090498`

Later SYM value can change to:
`SYM=034249822`
`SYM=BVZ342`

When loop through a file with a for loop and echo the SYM to a File like this:

`echo $SYM >> $TMP_RESULT_STORE`

The output would looks like this for the above entries:
90498
34249822
BVZ342

The leading zeros are lost.  I can get it to keep the zeros like this:

`echo ""\'$SYM" >> $TMP_RESULT_STORE`

But then it looks like this and I cannot get rid of the single quote(pls ignore the backward single quotes at the end. I was trying to get this site to write each entry to a new line and this was the best I can do):

'0090498
'034249822
'BVZ342```

Obviously, I'm doing other stuff in this script while scraping a log, I wanted to keep it simple to understand and just focus on the issue.

How can I get the bash script to keep the leading zeros when there is or are leading zeros using bash script?